# Can bot receive multiple consecutive messages when using microsoft bot framework?

Tags: botframework

I designed one bot with bot framework which needed user input two consecutive messages in 10 seconds.
I checked some official examples:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/

All of them are the format of one response corresponding to one input.

How to change code to make multiple consecutive input possible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Dialogs in bots can have multiple steps, and bots can handle multiple users at once. The amount of time between steps in a waterfall dialog, for example, is dependent on the amount of time needed for your operation to execute. Perhaps if you explained your scenario more clearly and/or provided some example code you tried to write?

Comment: Do you use instant messaging apps like Messenger or WhatsApp ? we often input multiple text one time, for example: hi\n Do you have time tonight\n How about have a   dinnier?  That's what I mean three consecutive messages. You may ask why I can't input three messages in one line. I can, but most users don't, they input anything what they like

Comment: That doesn't explain what your scenario is. For example, if your bot is an appointments bot for a gym, you wouldn't expect it to be able to handle various queries about restaurants, nor would you expect a user to interact with it as they would a human on an IM platform. The way you design your bot's dialogs depends on how the bot is to be used and what environment it's meant to operate in. The [multi-turn prompt](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/05.multi-turn-prompt) seems to be what you want, but you haven't been clear enough for me to know for sure.